# Can a brahmin boy marry a shudra girl?

Tags: vedas, manu-smriti

I am sahu from caste and my boyfriend whom I love very much is sharma. I never thought that this will come when I met him in college. I never had knowledge about this.. Jab mene college ke baad gurudiksha li to mujhe mere guruji ne bola ki intercaste marriage nai kr skti usse.. Nai to vo ladka brahmin hai uske ma baap or pitra paani accept nai karinge.. Or peedi kharab ho jaegi.. I don't want this to happen to him. I just want the best for him and his family.  I don't know if we can marry or what my guruji said I should follow that. I don't want to hurt him either. Just tell me Can a brahmin varna boy marry a shudra  varna girl?

Comment: The great Ved Vyasa creater of all the major scriptures was Rishi Parashar's son from Satyavati daughter of a fisherman ... hope you are getting my point.

Comment: This is a very opinion-based question and I'm voting to close it. What is caste and what isn't - is a very subjective topic and differs from sect to sect. In Arya Samaj, the vernas are re-assigned based on gunas and frequent marriage between vernas is acceptable too. In other older systems that follow older rules - smartas, shankaracharyas don't accept that. What you do and what you don't not be a matter of texts and scriptures, rather what your parents and gurus decide.

Comment: Thanks.. I am hopeful that my parents will agree to me marrying him but my guruji won't.. He is a brahmachari and of shankaracharya parampara too.